# SQL Function for updating column with values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Those who have helped me before, i tend to use SAS9.4 a lot for my day to day work, however there are times when i need to use SQL Server

There is a output table i have with 2 variables (attached output.csv)
[output table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dNbDm2NiU1el8IXCGtT7zP67ODR9ismK/view?usp=sharing)

ID, GROUP, DATE

The table has 830 rows:
330 have a "C" group
150 have a "A" group
50 have a "B" group

the remaining 300 have group as "TEMP"

within SQL i do not now how to programatically work out the total volume of A+B+C. The aim is to update "TEMP" column to ensure there is an Equal amount of "A" and "B" totalling 250 of each (the remainder of the total count)

so the table totals

330 have a "C" group
250 have a "A" group
250 have a "B" group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to proportion the "temp" to get equal amounts of "A" and "B".

So, the idea is to count up everything in A, B, and Temp and divide by 2.  That is the final group size.  Then you can use arithmetic to allocate the rows in Temp to the two groups:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum + a_cnt <= final_group_size then 'A' else 'B' end) as allocated_group
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
      where group = 'Temp'
     ) t cross join
     (select (cnt_a + cnt_b + cnt_temp) / 2 as final_group_size,
             g.*
      from (select sum(case when group = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_a,
                   sum(case when group = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_b,
                   sum(case when group = 'Temp' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_temp
            from t
           ) g
     ) g
```

SQL Server makes it easy to put this into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when seqnum + a_cnt <= final_group_size then 'A' else 'B' end) as allocated_group
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
            from t
            where group = 'Temp'
           ) t cross join
           (select (cnt_a + cnt_b + cnt_temp) / 2 as final_group_size,
                   g.*
            from (select sum(case when group = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_a,
                         sum(case when group = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_b,
                         sum(case when group = 'Temp' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_temp
                  from t
                 ) g
           ) g
      )
update toupdate
    set group = allocated_group;
```

Comment: `Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'newid'. This function is neither a registered`

Comment: @teelove . . . Your question says that you are using SQL Server, and this is definitely a SQL Server function:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: My bad - I am actually using SQL server, but just to test, i have tried it in databricks first whilst the server undergoes maintenance..

Comment: as soon as its back up and running i will double check

Comment: hello, server will be back up in 30 mins finally, just checking the syntax, what is select "t" and "g" refering to, are we creating temp tables here

Comment: had to change the a_cnt around in the third line but worked a treat..

Comment: thanks for getting me 99% the way there, i'm running the query without the update statement at the moment, but i'm running into problems where the allocations is not exactly even, i cant work out why, and each time i run it i get different results for A and B, not an exactl split

running a count i get

A = 244 
B = 256
C = 330 (correct)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a top 250 update style approach

```
update top (250) [TableName] set Group = 'A' where exists (Select * from [TableName] t2 where t2.id = [TableName].id order by newid()) and Group = 'Temp'

update top (250) [TableName] set Group = 'B' where exists (Select * from [TableName] t2 where t2.id = [TableName].id order by newid()) and Group = 'Temp'
```